# Change text box depending on what is clicked

Tags: html, css

I am using wordpress to maintain a website. I would like to create a page with a few icons and a text box at the bottom. Depending on what icon is clicked, the text in the box underneath changes. Does anyone know a way to d this using basic html and css?

Comment: This is not a code writing site.  Try something first.  Show us when it goes wrong, and we'll try to help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that questions asking for general help or recommendations are discouraged: See [Allowed Topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You are expected to have researched your issue and made attempts to solve it before posting. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with hidden checkboxes. And a little hack. 
Use the CSS sibling selector. This changes your styles on elements that are siblings on your checkbox. If the checkbox get's the pseudo-class :checked your text will change.

Try this out:

```
<input type="checkbox">
<p class="to-be-changed">Some Text.</p>

    .to-be-changed {
    color: black;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .to-be-changed {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's only possible for custom script

```js
$('#two').click(function(){
    $('#count').val('2');
    $('#total').text('Product price: $1000');
});

$('#four').click(function(){
    $('#count').val('4');
    $('#total').text('Product price: $2000');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id ='two' onclick="change()" value="2&#x00A;Qty">
<input type="button" id ='four' class="mnozstvi_sleva" value="4&#x00A;Qty">
<br>
Total <input type="text" id="count" value="">
```